# Using the ceil() function more advanced

Tags: c++, c, rounding, ceil

I am aware of what the ceil function does, it rounds numbers up.
So; 1.3 to 2.0 and 5.9 to 6.0.
But I want it to round up with steps of 0.5.
So; 1.3 to 1.5 and 5.9 to 6.0.
Is this possible?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Note: Once `|x|` exceeds about `power(2, DBL_MANT_DIG -1)`, `double` loses the ability to round to the nearest 0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = ceil(x * 2.0)/2.0;
```

should do what you need:

```
x     x*2.0   ceil(x*2.0)  y
------------------------------
1.3    2.6     3.0         1.5
1.6    3.2     4.0         2.0
5.9   11.8    12.0         6.0
```

Comment: Clever! I can't believe I didn't figure that out for myself! Thanks!